# Jquery- Getting values from inputs inside <td> into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase-realtime-database, css-selectors

I am attempting to get the input filled by the user from a table. The table has but 2 columns how can I get the input from these? I want to have a different var for each column of items?  The table changed size dynamically by a slider which controls the rows. This is my table:

```
<div id="table-gen">
            <p>Als je dezelfde herhaling doet voor alle sets, kan je slechts één waarde invullen: bvb. voor 4 sets
                slechts éénmaal 10 invoeren voor de herhalingen. Dit wordt dan automatisch 4 x 10.</p>
            <table id="resultTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Hoeveelheid</th>
                    <th scope="col">Gewicht x KG</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                    <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                    <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                    <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

this is what it looks Like:
[image]

I tried the following:

```
var col1_Array = $('#resultTable td:nth-child(1)').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

var col2_Array = $('#resultTable td:nth-child(2)').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

this only gives me the very first column and an emptry string. I try to upload it to firebase which goes well. Except the first column is the defeault number, after i change the size of my table it somehow doesnt register.

[image]

```
function writeData(){
    firebase.database().ref("Exercise").set({
        nameExercise: exerciseName.value,
        setAm: setAmount,
        setReps:col1_Array,
        weight:col2_Array,

    })
}
```

How can i best go around this dynamically changing table? Is it better to reconstruct this table to divs? I feel like im digging a rabbithole at this point..

Comment: Are you trying to get **text** from some `input` elements? Try to get their value instead.

Comment: The value of the input elements, as marked int eh first image. the 2 colums..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add classes  HoeveelheidField  and  GewichtField to td's

```
  <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td class="HoeveelheidField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
           <td class="GewichtField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
  </tr>
```

and then in order to get all values

```
function getData(){
$('#resultTable .HoeveelheidField > input ').each(function() {
  HoeveelheidArr.push($(this).val());
});
$('#resultTable .GewichtField > input').each(function() {
  Gewicht.push($(this).val());
});
```

Run this snippet to test if it works

```js
var HoeveelheidArr=[];
var Gewicht=[]
function getData(){
$('#resultTable .HoeveelheidField > input ').each(function() {
  HoeveelheidArr.push($(this).val());
});
$('#resultTable .GewichtField > input').each(function() {
  Gewicht.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(HoeveelheidArr);
console.log(Gewicht);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resultTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Hoeveelheid</th>
                    <th scope="col">Gewicht x KG</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td class="HoeveelheidField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                    <td class="GewichtField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td class="HoeveelheidField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                    <td class="GewichtField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td class="HoeveelheidField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                    <td class="GewichtField"><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button onclick="getData()">Get Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should target the `input` in order to map the values.

Then, Since an jQuery lookup like `$("#resultTable td:nth-child(2) input")` returns a jQuery collection of elements, you have to apply the `.get()` on it before mapping... Not after.

Third, in the selectors, `td:nth-child(n)` is **not** zero based.

Fourth, in `map()`, the argument is a function. That function needs an argument in order to return something from it. Notice the `input` in `.map(function (input) {`

I made it so the arrays are refreshed on `input` change... But I don't know if that is relevant to you. **Anyway**, you should use an event to achieve this. Also notice the use of [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), since your table is dynamically changing...

```js
var col1_Array, col2_Array;

$(document).on("change","#resultTable td input", function () {
  col1_Array = $("#resultTable td:nth-child(2) input")
    .get()
    .map(function (input) {
      return input.value;
    });
  col2_Array = $("#resultTable td:nth-child(3) input")
    .get()
    .map(function (input) {
      return input.value;
    });

  console.log(col1_Array, col2_Array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="table-gen">
  <p>Als je dezelfde herhaling doet voor alle sets, kan je slechts één waarde invullen: bvb. voor 4 sets
    slechts éénmaal 10 invoeren voor de herhalingen. Dit wordt dan automatisch 4 x 10.</p>
  <table id="resultTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col">Hoeveelheid</th>
      <th scope="col">Gewicht x KG</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1"></td>
      <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1"></td>
      <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1"></td>
      <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BaNvvNG?editors=1011)